# How can we use log4j2 with JBOSS a long with its default logging instead of overwriting

Tags: java, jboss, log4j2, slf4j

```
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
```

instead of excluding its default logging we need to include log4j for our custom logging

I exclude default logging from subsystems but i need that too. So how can include log4j2 properties file and where I should change the JBOSS settings

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using? Do you mean you want to configure logging through the logging subsystem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 7.4.12.GA
I don't know how many ways are to achieve the requirements I just need to add log4j and current default logging should be there in server.log